# How to have an archive with full paths, BUT without creating a tarbomb?

Tags: tar, zip

I want to create an archive file that preserves the absolute path information of the originals, but I have not been able to find a way to do this that does not result in a tarbomb?

For concreteness, suppose that I want to make a (compressed) archive file (*.zip or *.tgz or anything else) that includes the files

```
/usr/share/foo/bsd/config.yaml
/usr/share/foo/linux/config.yaml
/usr/share/foo/windows/config.yaml
```

...and I want to preserve the information encoded in the full path of the original files.

Ideally, when the archive is extracted, it should produce the following files

```
./<BASENAME>/usr/share/foo/bsd/config.yaml
./<BASENAME>/usr/share/foo/linux/config.yaml
./<BASENAME>/usr/share/foo/windows/config.yaml
```

...where `<BASENAME>` stands for the archive file's basename (EXcluding its extension).

One way I could do this would be to create `./<BASENAME>/usr/share/foo/{bsd,linux,windows}` directories, create symlinks in these directories to the corresponding files, create an archive of the `./<BASENAME>` directory (including whatever flag may be needed to ensure that the symlinks get dereferenced at the time of adding items to the archive), and run `rm -rf ./<BASENAME>` once the archive file is ready.

Is there a less labored approach?

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be similar to the following:

`tar -Pczvf ./test.tgz /usr/share/foo/{bsd,linux,windows}`

> Using GNU TAR:
> -P: absolute names
> -c: create
> -z: gzip compression
> -v: verbose output
> -f: file name for archive

This would give you a compressed archive with the absolute paths for the included files.  Then you could extract the archive onto any base you would like using `-C`, or just extract the files to the absolute locations by using `-P` again:

`tar -xzvf ./test.tgz -C $BASENAME`
`tar -Pxzvf ./test.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using relative paths, something like:

```
cd /
tar cvf path/to/tar_file.tar usr/share/foo/{bsd,linux,windows}/config.yaml
```

so you have the path w/o leading slash.